# Tool to run compilation / tests before actually committing to the source control server?

Tags: git, svn, version-control, continuous-integration

I was wondering if there was some sort of tool that would allow me to prevent broken commits (commits that will make the trunk not compile) to actually happen in the trunk, or some special branches.

We actually run a CI server, but the best it can do at the moment is checking out the latest commits and compile / run tests over them, mailing my team if there's something wrong.

I would prefer, if possible, to have a system where only valid commits are allowed in the trunk, even if it means we'd have to wait a bit to see the actual commit in the trunk.

Implicit in my request is that the developers would continue to feel they are working directly with svn / git. It would of course be possible to do some hand-crafted tool to accomplish what I'm asking, but we like the ideia of using Tortoisegit / Tortoisesvn / EGit / Subversive if possible.

Does such a tool exist (that works with either git or SVN)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about any tools which would fit your description but you can do it the "git" way by structuring your branches into three categories:

- **feature/task** branches : this is where the actual work happens.
- a single **integration/staging** branch : this is where the feature or task branches get merged - this should always be tested and it's expected that it'll sometime fail.
- a single **production** branch : should only contain green builds, merged from the integration/staging branch. This is the "main" branch, the one you can deploy to production.

I think this should help you solve your problem of an "always green" branch if I understood correctly what you would like to achieve.

There's also a great (but a bit long) Atlassian webinar video about efficient git branching strategies/workflows, including some useful notes about CI systems as well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O4SoB3TFkjA